# What does the phrase "for the heck of it" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "for the heck of it" mean?

For example, I just found this in a book:

> — I just dusted the dining room for the heck of it!
>   — How thoughtful of you!

Comment: Would be nice to know the origin as well, but I guess Sam already described it below =)

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+heck+of+it

Comment: That was my first question, now I've realized what kind of questions can be asked here.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [minced oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) version of "*for the hell of it*" which means without a particular reason, typically done for fun or enjoyment (fun and enjoyment being presumably things you would go to hell for).

Comment: _Heck_ may be freely substituted for [_hell_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html) in any idiom.  BTW, "minced oath" is a 19th century term and means nothing to most English speakers; the modern one is _Euphemism_, which is probably not in most vocabularies, either, but has the benefit of being widely used and searchable.

Comment: What is wrong with http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+heck+of+it The OP asked for the meaning, not a hypernym.